# adjust arff file format for WEKA

Tags: weka, arff

I wnat to make preprocessing for Weka arff file which contains 2000 lines
for nlp project (sentiment analysis)

I want a code that just add a single quotation at the start and end of each sentence. for example this is a sample for my dataset:

```
The Da Vinci Code is one of the most beautiful movies ive ever seen.,1
The Da Vinci Code is an * amazing * book, do not get me wrong.,1
then I turn on the light and the radio and enjoy my Da Vinci Code.,1
The Da Vinci Code was REALLY good.,1
i love da vinci code....,1
```

I want the output to be:

```
'The Da Vinci Code is one of the most beautiful movies ive ever seen.',1
'The Da Vinci Code is an * amazing * book, do not get me wrong.',1
'then I turn on the light and the radio and enjoy my Da Vinci Code.',1
'The Da Vinci Code was REALLY good.',1
'i love da vinci code....',1
```

Just want to add a single quotation at the beginning and end of each sentence (before the 1 ).

I would really appreciate it if you help me do it

Is there any tool that I can use instead of writing a code?

Comment: Can you edit your question with information about what you have tried to accomplish what you want, and where it failed? Please also explain why C++ is mentioned specifically.

Answer (score 0):

You could use Regular Expressions to achieve this. [Regular expressions are a powerful formalism for pattern matching in strings.](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/regex/info) A large amount of existing tools support Regular Expressions, which allows you to match/replace the texts you want without the need to write any code yourself.

To match and replace using Regular Expressions (regexp), you need two parts:

1. Match: An expression to match something in your string or strings.
2. Substitution/Replace: An expression to indicate what to replace an
   match with.

**Match:**

```
/([^\.]+)(\.+)(,1\s+)/g
```

- Group 1: Match all characters except for a literal dot, at least 1
  character.
- Group 2: Match only literal dots, at least 1 character.
- Group 3: Match a literal comma, followed by a literal 1, followed by
  at least 1 whitespace character.
- Regex flag **g** (global): multiple matches

**Substitution:**

```
'$1$2'$3
```

- Enclose group 1 and 2 with quotes, followed by group 3.

You can view an interactive version of the above Match and Substitution [here](https://regex101.com/r/FNgtls/2)

Now you can use that match and substitution to work with your favorite regexp tool.

Like [sed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sed):

```
sed -i -E "s/([^\.]+)(\.+)(,1\s+)/'\1\2'\3/g" yourfile.txt
```

Or Windows [PowerShell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PowerShell):

```
(Get-Content yourfile.txt) -replace '([^\.]+)(\.+)(,1\s+)', '''$1$2''$3' | Out-File output.txt
```

<sub>Other tools might use a different syntax. Provided match/substitution patterns can probably be optimized further.</sub>

Comment: I actually did not get all what you just said, as I am not familiar with the regular expression. Can you please help me do it?

Comment: @A.Atiyah I expanded my answer with some basic information about RegExp and included a second example of how to use it (using PowerShell).